# Mysql - How to get Newsfeed from users you follow

Tags: php, mysql

I've been working on this for some hours now and it's getting tiring. I want to get users posts from people I follow and myself, just like twitter does.

So there's a table `users_posts` that has all users' posts with column `user_id` to determine who made the post.

Another table `users_followers` that contains all followers ie. `user_id` follows `following_id`

So here's my query:

User ID = 2271

```
SELECT users_followers.following_id AS following_id, users_posts.id
FROM users_followers, users_posts
WHERE users_posts.user_id = users_followers.following_id
AND (users_followers.user_id =2271)
```

This query works but the problem is, it's kinda slow. Is there a faster way to do this?

Also, as you can see, I can only get posts from those I follow, and not myself.

Any help?

Comment: Query seems fine; doesn't need the parentheses. Maybe search query optimization and indexes

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your tables properly, I would do this with an explicit `JOIN`. I'm not sure how much that would speed things up versus the implicit `JOIN` you're using though.

```
SELECT following_id, p.id
FROM users_followers f
LEFT JOIN users_posts p
    ON (p.user_id = f.following_id)
WHERE f.user_id = 2271
```

Chances are, adding an index or two to your tables would help.

Using the MySQL [`EXPLAIN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain.html) command (just put it in front of your `SELECT` query) will show the indexes, temporary tables, and other resources that are used for a query. It should give you an idea when one query is faster or more efficient than another.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Both queries takes same time but I was missing out on indexing...

Answer (score 0):

Your query is fine as written, provided you have properly indexed your tables. At a minimum you need an index on users_posts.user_id and users_followers.following_id.

A query can also be slowed by large numbers of records, even when it is fully indexed. In that case, I find phpmyadmin to be an invaluable tool.  From the server page (maybe localhost) select the Status tab to see a wealth of information about how your mysql server is performing and suggestions for how to improve it.